# Apply the same Conditional format rule _dynamically_ to a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

On a Google spreadsheet file, I have two sheets, sheet1 and sheet2. I would like to apply the following conditional formatting to column A of sheet2.

For each row i of sheet2:

- if Ai < A'i : apply a color red
- if Ai > A'i : apply a color green
- if Ai = A'i : apply a color yellow

where:

- Ai is the cell on column A and row i of sheet2
- A'i is the cell on column A and row i of sheet1

Is there a way to do this other than manually on each cell of column A of sheet2 ?

Here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqYP9nHxrSVROeTtpcHZkRrm60TJKxJ2hSiah-mPYfk/edit#gid=2116258606
where I used the following non working formula :

```
=index(indirect("Sheet1!A2"))>A2
=index(indirect("Sheet1!A2"))<A2
=index(indirect("Sheet1!A2"))=A2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

red color:

```
=A2<INDIRECT("Sheet1!A$2:A")
```

green color:

```
=A2>INDIRECT("Sheet1!A$2:A")
```

yellow color:

```
=(A2=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A$2:A"))*(A2<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi @player0, thank. you for the formula. What does A2<>"" mean, and what is the difference between A2 and A$2 ? I just added the formula that I tried first but that didn'y work. Could you explain to me what was causing the formula not to work ?

Comment: A2<>"" means: "if cells in A column are not empty". $ in A$2 is a lock so we lock the range to be A2:A.

Comment: Why do we need to have *(A2<>"") in the last formula and not in the first two ??

Comment: because without it you would get yellow cells for A8, A9, A10, A11 etc (if you look at the picture from the answer)